# Bind DHCP Config with LDAP Database without DHCP-ISC

Tags: ldap, dhcp

I want to get my DHCP Config from LDAP-Database. Especially the subnet hosts should be migrated there. However, I don't find a lot of information about this procedure. Is it not recommended? I principally found information about DHCP-ISC but the website says they stopped the support since 2022.

LAM has a DHCP support https://www.ldap-account-manager.org/static/doc/manual/ch04s12.html but I cannot find an schema objectclass for dhcpServer.